# part data instead of splitting data?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can I say part data instead of splitting data?

"To keep tracking of this, part data, checking incoming packets, generating header, etc, many mechanisms are available to facilitate the communication between the client and server."

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=part+data%2C+split+data&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpart%20data%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csplit%20data%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Synonyms rarely have total overlap of their distributions (a powerful computer and strong tea, but not ...). Unless technobabble has overtaken us in this example, you can't substitute _parting_ for _splitting_ here.

Comment: When you say "part data" most people will wonder whether they're auto parts or parts of some other device.

Comment: You can part your hair, you can part *with** something or someone, and Moses could part the Red Sea, but I can't think of many other contexts where _part_ is used to mean splitting something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for *parsing* data, because I don't see how either *splitting* data or *parting* data could work in this context.

Comment: There are many references to 'data splitting' on the internet.

Comment: Oh absolutely! I'm not trying to argue otherwise, I just don't see it in this context. The jargon could be throwing me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question would be a little easier to answer if it had more information. Nevertheless, based on the quote you provided, I believe you are writing about Layer 4, the [Transport Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_layer), of the [OSI Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

> "To keep tracking of this, part data, checking incoming packets, generating header, etc, many mechanisms are available to facilitate the communication between the client and server."

I believe you are writing about Layer 4 because that layer verifies delivery of packets of data and sequences the packets ("checking incoming packets"), and to do those things it must add information to the packets of data as a header ("generating header"). Finally, if the data to be transmitted is too large for the protocol's maximum size, then the protocol at Layer 4 divides the data into smaller portions. The technical term for this process is [**segmentation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_segmentation).

If you are in fact speaking about a technical process, then it is poor style to deviate from established terms with specific, technical meanings. @EditingInStyle is correct, however, that "parsing" is typically the go-to word for dividing data when speaking about computers.

If you are writing about packet/data segmentation, however, then parsing, splitting, and parting are all incorrect terms. The data itself is not parsed, split, or parted: it is segmented for transmission but the segmentation is transparent to the client and to the server. Compare to the process of splitting a database of employees into two databases: one for men and one for women. In that instance, the data is split.

**Conclusion: if you are writing about data transmission protocols, then it is almost certain that the *only* appropriate word is segmentation.**

Comment: Yup, *parsing* was a guess since I didn't know what he was trying to say, but could tell the other words weren't quite right. *Segmentation* is much more likely to be the correct answer here.

Comment: I taught the OSI Model at a technical school, so I had a small advantage here. :) It is the most difficult material in that particular course, so I very much understand how hard it is to explain the model.